# iOS 8: NSURLQueryItem with empty value

Tags: ios8

for an http get request's query string ?text=&index=10, how one can generate NSURLQueryItem for first key 'text' with empty value? Or does above kind of query string generation not supported by NSURLComponents ?

Comment: What's wrong with `NSURLQueryItem(name:"text", value:"")` ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually earlier what I am trying to accomplish is creating a category on NSDictionary that will return array of NSURLQueryItems after parsing through its key-value pairs. For some keys like 'text', I am passing [NSNull null] as value and so unable to generate the needed NSURLQueryItems array. But then specifying @"" as value in the key for NSDictionary and also suggested by @Alladinian in the comment above the problem has been solved.